# firebase get id by for delete

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase

How I can delete or change item by object in firebase? I need to add id field for all rows in the base ? All examples what found showd how output id in console from id object field.

```
<div class="well span8" id="messagesDiv">

    <div class="well span3 pull-left note" ng-repeat="msg in messages">
        <button type='button' class='close' ng-click="deleteItem( msg )">×</button>
        <b>
        {{msg.time| date: 'longDate'}}
        </b>
        <br>{{msg.title}}
        <br>{{msg.body}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an html directive for Angular. Where do ids or Firebase enter the picture? Can you include that code as well, so we can see what you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the key for the objects in addition to value and them pass them to the `$remove` method:

```
<div class="well span3 pull-left note" ng-repeat="(key, msg) in messages">
  <button type='button' class='close' ng-click="messages.$remove(key)">×</button>
  ...
</div>
```

Assuming of course that `messages` is an instance of $firebase (provided by [angularFire](http://angularfire.com)):

```
$scope.messages = $firebase(new Firebase(URL));
```